# ffmpeg critical noise occured after silence remove filtering

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, filtering, noise, noise-reduction

I've tried to remove silence duration in my audio file.
and it seems like working well..
but some problem rose up like the picutre i attached.

```
ffmpeg -i "D://mono_test/silenceremove_test_raw.mp3" -filter:a silenceremove=1:0:-66dB -b:a 192k "D://mono_test/silenceremove_test.mp3"
```

after silence remove filtering(in ffmpeg), some noise occured like picture(just left channel in the file). already control all parameters about silenceremove method, but the problem doesn't disappear.

any Ideas?

please help me..
thnx.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nt1bD.jpg)

add full ffmpeg log here

```
ffmpeg version N-93986-gd3f236b300 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg C:\Users\drunk>ffmpeg -i "D://mono_test/silenceremove_test_raw.mp3" -filter:a silenceremove=1:0:-66dB -b:a 192k "D://mono_test/silenceremove_test.mp3"
ffmpeg version N-93986-gd3f236b300 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.3.1 (GCC) 20190414
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 28.100 / 56. 28.100
  libavcodec     58. 52.102 / 58. 52.102
  libavformat    58. 27.103 / 58. 27.103
  libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavfilter     7. 55.100 /  7. 55.100
  libswscale      5.  4.101 /  5.  4.101
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
Input #0, mp3, from 'D://mono_test/silenceremove_test_raw.mp3':
  Metadata:
    title           : 190604_0026.mp3
    album           : TASCAM DR-07MK2
    genre           : Other
    encoder         : Lavf58.27.103
    id3v2_priv.XMP  : <?xpacket begin="\xef\xbb\xbf" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>\x0a<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="3.1.2-113">\x0a <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">\x0a  <rdf:Description rdf:about=""\x0a    xmlns:dc="http://pur
  Duration: 00:00:57.91, start: 0.011995, bitrate: 214 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavf
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp3 (mp3float) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mp3, to 'D://mono_test/silenceremove_test.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TIT2            : 190604_0026.mp3
    TALB            : TASCAM DR-07MK2
    TCON            : Other
    id3v2_priv.XMP  : <?xpacket begin="\xef\xbb\xbf" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>\x0a<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="3.1.2-113">\x0a <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">\x0a  <rdf:Description rdf:about=""\x0a    xmlns:dc="http://pur
    TSSE            : Lavf58.27.103
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.52.102 libmp3lame
size=    1329kB time=00:00:56.55 bitrate= 192.6kbits/s speed=73.3x
video:0kB audio:1326kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.247506%
```

and i also share my audio file here ↓↓↓

**https://drive.google.com/open?id=1r-V-xesdO8pQ9_HGMweBUm6b0QRxwql2**

silenceremove_test_raw.mp3 <- this file is original data before silenceremove process.

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: @Gyan thnx, I repost with full log

Comment: Share file if possible.

Comment: @llogan thnx for comments. I repost with my audio file sharing drive link.